# Update Quantity in shopping cart with dropdownlist onchange event in ListView

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu, shopping-cart

i have a shopping cart solution written with Asp.Net .
in Cart Web Page, i have a list view for products and each item has a dropdownlist for quantity .
i want to update total price of each item when user change quantity .
i want to use jquery and onchange event of dropdownlist .

```
 <asp:ListView ID="repItemList" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID">

     <LayoutTemplate>

         <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
     </LayoutTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <div class="margin">
         <table class="tbl">
              <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td class="four">
                         <table>
                             <tbody>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td class="fone"><%# Eval("Total")%></td>
                                    <td class="ftwo">
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="lstCount" runat="server" CssClass="DropDownList" onchange="" >
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1" />
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2" />
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3" />
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4" />
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="5" />

                                       </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="ffour"><%# Eval("Price")%>
                                    </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the drop down value on change like,

```
$('.ftwo').change(function(){
    var price=$(this).closest('tr').find('.fone').html();
    var quantity =$(this).val();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.ffour').html(price * quantity);
});
```

you can refer [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jgz2x/)

Comment: Does not Work for me! I guess because dropdownlist is in listview .

Comment: in listview , for each row , i has a dropdownlist and want to update total price of each row when user change dropdownlist value.

Comment: where i write jquery?

Comment: Your jquery should be within `script` tag like, <script type="text/javascript"> your jquery </script> in your page

Comment: work fine ! thank you. which code should i write to get default dropdownlist value from database?

Comment: I'm working on a project that I want you to help me.can i send private messages to you?

Comment: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/10/showbind-data-to-aspnet-dropdownlist.html.... you can refer this article for binding dropdownlist  from db